# iOS 15 Simulator - collection view cells rendering broken when scrolling...?

Tags: ios, rendering, simulator, collectionview, xcode13

I'm running my App on latest Xcode 13, running my app on iOS 15 in the simulator creates weird rendering bug / issue, when scrolling table rows (that contain collection views) horizontally. This is only visual. Touch points on cells are all ok, and I can scroll with my finger where the rendering doesn't...

[image: scrolling horizontally breaks rendering]

This is a table of collection views...

Also if I scroll the table vertically any rendering glitches are resolved...until I scroll left to right again.

Comment: Maybe it is an Xcode simulator bug, Does it behave the same in iPhone?

Comment: No, this is only happening on the simulator. It's quite distracting...grrr. Only happening to me?

Comment: Then it's a Xcode bug.   Try running on another simulator or add new simulator.

Comment: iPod simulator should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I had almost related UI issues after updating to new Xcode 13.
After reviewing my autoLayout code I found out that I was adding subViews as children of a collectionViewCell rather than it's contentView, as a side note this used to work on Xcode 12.x and lower.

So to fix the bug, all I had to do was: -

```swift
// instead of doing this: - 
self.addSubView(YourChildView)

// It should be: - 
self.contentView.addSubView(YourChildView)

// Then proceed with other layout stuffs
```